# Cómo pasar una variable externa a un XSLT

Tags: php, xml, variables-globales

Buenas tengo un archivo XML con muchos escritores del tipo:

```
<autores>
  <autor>
    <nombre>Cervantes</nombre>
    <nacionalidad>Española</nacionalidad>
    <bio>Escritor y dramaturgo español</bio>
    <bibliografia>
      <libro>La Galatea</libro>
      <libro>El Quijote</libro>
    </bibliografia>
  </autor>
  <autor>...</autor>
</autores>
```

y un archivo XSLT para filtrar por un determinado autor:

```
<xsl:for-each select="liberrete/autores/autor[nombre='Cervantes']">
  <xsl:value-of select="nombre"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="nacionalidad"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="bio"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="bibliografia/libro">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo llevar el nombre del autor como variable recogida en un archivo HTML (`<a href="">Cervantes</a>` por ejemplo) hasta el XSLT?

La cuestión es que si tuviera mil autores no tener que realizar mil páginas sin con tener todal la info en un XML puedo filtrarlos uno a uno con XSLT.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías definir en el XSLT una parámetro llamado NombreAutor por ejemplo, enviárselo  y luego referenciarlo en el for-each.

Ej:

```
<xsl:param name="NombreAutor"/>

<xsl:for-each select="liberrete/autores/autor[string(nombre)=string($NombreAutor)]">
```